# jqgrid is not a function using onSelectRow

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

I've seen a lot of similar issues on this site, so I apologize is this is a duplicate of an issue I didn't understand the answer for. But here it is: my trouble is "**jQuery("#tmpgrid").getCell is not a function**" (via firebug) when this code block is triggered

```
        onSelectRow: function (id) {
            var listid = jQuery('#tmpgrid').getCell(id, "Item id");
            $(window.location).attr('href', '/template/details/' + listid);
        }
```

within this asp.net mvc partial page

```
<table id="tmpgrid">
</table>
<div id="tmppager">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var grid = $('#tmpgrid');
    grid.jqGrid({
        url: '/template/jsontemplate',
        datatype: "json",
        height: "auto",
        autowidth: true,
        colNames: ['Item id', 'Title', 'Create Date', 'Edit Date', 'Public'],
        colModel: [
        { name: "id", index: "id", width: 25, search: false },
        { name: "Title", index: "Title", search: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['cn']} },
        { name: "CreateDate", index: "CreateDate", width: 50, search: false },
        { name: "EditDate", index: "EditDate", width: 50, search: false },
        { name: "IsPublic", index: "IsPublic", width: 25, search: false }
        ],
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        pager: '#pager',
        sortname: 'CreateDate',
        emptyrecords: 'No records to display',
        ignoreCase: true,
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: "My Checklists",
        onSelectRow: function (id) {
            var listid = jQuery('#tmpgrid').getCell(id, "Item id");
            $(window.location).attr('href', '/template/details/' + listid);
        }
    });
    grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#tmppager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, searchtext: 'Search' });
</script>
```

I've seen [Oleg's posts](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/jqgrid-3-7-2-bug-with-ie8-while-using-jqgrid-debugging/#p21510) about script loading/ordering issues, but I don't believe this is my problem (or maybe I'm not understanding the solution properly) - since I'm not using a developer release and thus only have 2 js files: "grid.locale-en.js" and "jquery.jqgrid.min.js". Also, I'm not sure if this still applies to the jqgrid versions past 3.7.2. I'm using the recent 4.0.0 release

I'm banging my head against a wall here. Any ideas?

Comment: another note: I've tried a permutations of the getCell command. There seem to be 3-4 ways to do the syntax, but all so far have led me to the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think jqGrid uses the jQuery-UI style method calls. Based on [these examples](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html), you need to call `getCell` like this:

```
$('#tmpgrid').jqGrid('getCell', id, 'Item id');
```

Comment: I did try this as well, with the same result. "jqGrid is not a function" - the bane of my existence! I think there may something unusual about calling jqGrid from inside of a function. For instance, when I wrap all the script items inside of $(document).ready, then the first call of grid.jqGrid says it's not a function.

Comment: And you are certain that you're including the jQuery and jqGrid JavaScript files, right? Any chance that you could set up an example on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your suggestion to use jsfiddle led me down the right path to find my telerik problem

Answer (score 2):

Would you believe it was an interaction with another script? I have some telerik components on the site and when I pulled their @Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar() component out, then jqGrid started working right.

Hmmm... Now to wean myself off those telerik components. I'd been planning this anyway.

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I too am suffering at the hands of Telerik! I read this article (http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/introduction-using-jquery.html) that says that when you use Telerik, Jquery is included in the page automatically, yet $ is always undefined... But when I add Jquery manually - I get the same type of issues that you are having

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, that you have to use "new API" style. What I mean is you included jqGrid JavaScripts in about as following form (see [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ahowto_grid_base#configuring_jqgrid_to_use_only_the_new_api)):

```
<script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
</script>
<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In the case you should "new API" style for the most jqGrid methods which you use. For example

```
var listid = jQuery('#tmpgrid').jqGrid('getCell', id, "Item id");
```

instead of

```
var listid = jQuery('#tmpgrid').getCell(id, "Item id");
```

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mind just solved this one - $('#xyz'), is the same as $get('#xyz') - which returns a dom object, that you can only call dom methods on.

However $find(), will get you the actual object with its expected methods